# Why not all of the dependencies are detected in the setup project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, setup-project

I built a little Windows Forms game and I want to create a setup file now.

Already created for its first version and all worked well, but when I created the next version of the game, and added the dependency WMPLib (wmp.dll), it wasn't a part of the Detected Dependencies folder in the Setup Project. Tried to switch between Release mode and Debug mode, also refreshed dependencies - didn't work.

[image]

Tried to add the dependency to the project directory in the Setup Project, but didn't work.
Also tried to remove the dependency and add it again, also didn't work.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: My guess is because wmp.dll is a system library, the setup skips it, which would be correct behavior. You shouldn't need or want to deploy OS components.

Comment: Ok, but if I if the dependency isn't added the sound isn't working at all in my Game form. If I do want to use it, how can I?

Comment: I'm not really sure, you may see if this helps... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/using-the-windows-media-player-control-with-microsoft-visual-studio#distributing-your-application